# Single display for multiple os and switching like workspace

Tags: linux, windows, macos

If you got like 3 different computers at home, mac os, linux and pc, and you have triple monitor setup for your pc, is it possible to switch to the other os like a workspace and they should also be able to display properly on triple monitor?

synergy is close, but it needs it's own display,.. it only shares the mouse and keyboard.

Comment: I do it - if I have to - by just pressing the input button on each monitor. Tedious but I don't do it often. What I normally do is work entirely on my Mac, remoted into the PC, even though it's right there next to me. That eliminates the need to switch keyboard & mouse. For anything else, I use VMs.

Answer (score 2):

This is the purpose of a [KVM switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch). KVM switches tie a single keyboard, video/display, and mouse to 2 or more computers. Most switch back and forth by toggling Scroll Lock or an external button.

There isn't an exclusively software solution to this since it requires changing video inputs either via cables themselves or switching input sources on the display.

Answer (score 1):

If you can plug in all your computers into different inputs on all your monitors at the same time, **you might be able to get the monitors to switch between the inputs from software using ddc/ci commands**.

You could even set up Synergy with the following layout and automatically run your input switcher script when the mouse is entering a different row:

```
+-----------------+
|     |     |     |
| win | win | win |
|     |     |     |
+-----------------+
|     |     |     |
|linux|linux|linux|
|     |     |     |
+-----------------+
|     |     |     |
| OSX | OSX | OSX |
|     |     |     |
+-----------------+
```

See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/860761/ubuntu-command-line-to-change-input-source-on-a-display-monitor/861059

See: https://github.com/magdesign/Synergy-monitor-switcher/blob/master/README.md

Comment: This is awesome. I'll be adding this to my own Synergy environment and cutting down on a few monitors. For those with a Windows server, Nir Sofer has created [ControlMyMonitor](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/control_my_monitor.html)

Answer (score 0):

You also have the option of leaving at least 2 of them available for Remote Desktop, VNC, or other similar solutions.  On MacOS, I use the modern Microsoft Remote Desktop, which lets me copy-paste between multiple Windows RDP sessions.

Of course, you'd have to have the systems set up ahead of time for it, and be fairly stable.  If you regularly do hardware changes or access GRUB or clean-sweep OS formats, then KVM is better.